# Deleting an object by object ID - Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I am trying to delete an object in my database by his objectID.
I know is objectID (choosenID), which is created by xcode.

I have done this:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Notes")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectID = %@", "\(choosenID)")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                print ("Note:")
                if let designation = result.value(forKey: "designation") {
                    print("Designation: \(designation)")
                }

                  context.delete(result)

                 do {
                     try context.save()
                 } catch {
                     print("failed to delete note")
                 }   
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print ("Error in do")
    }
```

If I do something like this with an entity atribute it works ok. But with objectID (NSManagedObjectID) it's not working and app crashes.
Any tips how to fix this please?

EDIT: This is the crash message:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath objectID not found in entity '    (...)   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

I see I cannot use objectID in predicate.... I tried to use SELF and it doesn't work....

Comment: Please post crash log and `choosenID` creation

Comment: DOne that. I tried using request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF = %@", "\(choosenID)") and still doesn't work. I managed to make this work using  object(with: ( ...)).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29076081/1457385

Comment: That's it :) I done that....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get core data entity by it's objectID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075910/how-can-i-get-core-data-entity-by-its-objectid)

Comment: Hello from the future! Having this problem as well. Can't find a fix.